# MS PROJECT 2010 VBA: Initialisation of event handler class object lost?

Tags: vba, event-handling, ms-project

First: I am working with MS Project 2010 on Windows 7.

My question: I have created an event handler class EventClassModule where I handle events that occur when tasks are created as well as when one special field is changed.

I have an Initialize_App routine:
[image: Initialize App routine]

The class instance is initialized upon opening of the project:
[image]

Everything works fine and the events are handled as long as no unforeseen error occurs, i.e., an error thrown by the application that is not handled by my program and forces the user the halt the program somewhere in the middle. Afterwards, the eventhandling does not work any more until one runs the Auto_Open sub manually again.

While of course I try to handle all possible errors such that the program is ended correctly, I want to understand while it seems that the initialization is lost.

Comment: Why do they delete my "Dear all"? Well, please feel greeted! ;-)

Comment: Things like “deal all”, “anyone have an idea?”, “thanks in advance”, “best regards”, and signing your name at the end are all unnecessary and should be removed when asking a question.

Comment: It’s also a good idea to copy code as code blocks instead in photos. They can’t be searched, are harder to copy to test your code, and in general difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have answered your own question. As you stated unhandled errors force the user to "halt the program" and your events don't fire again until your handler is re-initialized. That's exactly right. When the program is halted the code has stopped running and needs to be re-initialized. You already know the solution to this problem--handle ALL errors. At a minimum, make sure all of your code is encapsulated in an error handler, even if it is only done via `On Error Resume Next`.